# Safari tables positioning (negative margins)

Tags: html, css, safari, html-table, margin

I've encountered a very odd bug on safari, and was wondering if anyone could shed any light on it. I'll preface this by saying it works absolutely perfect on Chrome and Firefox, but breaks on Safari and Safari and Chrome on Apple devices.

Here is a codepen illustrating my issue:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wWkBOB

<sup>`the code is too much to include here and much clearer on the codepen.`</sup>

I have 3 tables, wanting to line up on desktop size so they are all on the same line, with only the first having the 1st column showing so it appears as one large table (but needs to be 3 separate tables for mobile). On my centre table, I have a negative right margin of 12.5% to allow for all three tables to be 37.5% wide, and the third table sits over the end of the centre one.

On safari, this does not work on the 3rd table sits below. If you inspect the centre table, you can see that the computed value of the 12.5% negative margin at full size is 160px. If I then go back to the styles and change it to -160px instead of a percentage value, it works absolutely fine. The percentage value it wants to be able to look correctly is -20%.

Setting it at -20% obviously isn't correct for the other browsers and doesn't make any sense, as the value wanted is 160px which is 12.5%.

Any ideas? Help? Suggestions? would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well. I fixed it by adding

```
position: absolute
```

in the css to the tags that were acting strange try it maybe it will work for you

else your could try to use pixels